# How to pass data as a Form data to webapi from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am sending an object from UI to API controller. Below is the contoller from UI

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Update(string Id, string Desc..)
{
   ViewBag.API_CORE_URL = _config["API_CORE_URL"];
   Object obj = new Object();
    
   obj.ScenarioId = Id;
   obj.ScenarioDesc = Desc;
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
        var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync($"{ViewBag.API_CORE_URL}api/Account/ExecuteObj", obj).Result;
    return Ok(result);
   }
}


//WebAPI Controller
[HttpPost]
[Route("ExecuteObj")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExecuteObj([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dataSourceRequest, [FromForm]ExecuteDataSourceRequest executeDataSourceRequest)
{
    if (HttpContext.User.Identity.Name != null)
    {
        DvfwUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        executeDataSourceRequest.UserId = user.ssoUserId;
        DataSourceRequestMapHelper.SetDataRequestObject(executeDataSourceRequest, dataSourceRequest);
        var executionSummaries = _accountRepository.GetExecutedata(executeDataSourceRequest);

        return Ok(executionSummaries);
    }
    else
        return Unauthorized();
}
```

I don't get any value in executeDataSourceRequest. How do I get the object I am paasing from UI?

Comment: kindly add the request URL and the sample payload to the description